# Automatically added brs and paragraphs?

Tags: posts, shortcode, editor, formatting

Here's my very simple shortcode:

```
function box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'width' => 'auto',
            'height' => 'auto', 
            ), $atts ) );  

       return '<div class="boxy-box" style="width:'. $width .'; height:'. $height .';" >'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
    }

    add_shortcode('box', 'box_shortcode');
```

> [box]something[/box]

should give:

```
<div class="boxy-box" width:auto; height:auto;>something</div>
```

But, it doesn't. Even an empty shortcode (without a content, eg. [box][/box]) gives:

```
<div class="boxy-box" width:auto; height:auto;><br/></div>
```

(I don't care, but don't know where the br comes from)

The main problem is that, when I try [box]something[/box] I'm getting:

```
<div class="boxy-box" width:auto; height:auto;><br/>something<br/></div>
```

I know WP editor formats text automatically and there are "noP" plugins out there, but firstly - I'm using the HTML editor, secondly, why the heck WP is adding Brs (sometimes p's) to an inline code? :O

It wouldn't be a huge problem, but I HAVE to get PURE output, so:

```
[box]<h1>Header</h1><div>Content</div>[/box]
```

Will give a header and a div inside my box div, without any parapgrahs, brs, spans etc.

The funny thing is I have the same shortcode with h2 instead of div and it doesn't give any brs etc.

Sometimes I'm also getting a 
`<div class="boxy-box" width:auto; height:auto;></p>$content (...)`

[edit]

I've found some comments on it:

> This is driving me nuts as well. What
>   the f**k is the point of having a
>   html/code mode for posting if
>   wordpress filters the god damn code
>   and wraps around the tags anyways?

So I guess that's the problem. Is there a way of turning autop functionality at least for HTML editor? ;/

Comment: Is there a particular reason you call `do_shortcode` inside the shortcode function, are you expecting other shortcodes inside your own? If not, i'd suggest testing minus the do_shortcode call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can postpone the wp_autop filter. Wordpress has this filter enabled by default. And it is processing before the shortcode output.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Add this to your `functions.php` and check if the problem persist!

See a similar problem here: [stray <p> elements](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11134/stray-p-elements)

Comment: actually I did that, but I believe it won't create ps while writing posts anymore? :(

Comment: ok, got it. +30 points for You!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're still here, but I have some wpautop trouble :) Here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15137/formatting-code

Comment: I have seen a few "solutions" to this problem on SE and other places, and none of them have worked until I found yours. I wish I could +100 this answer and bitchslap the authors of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and checked the $content in the add_filter() function. There you can see what happen with the shortcodes. I ended up with an easy plugin, that removes p and br tags on shortcodes:
http://www.johannheyne.de/wordpress/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

The filter works but messes up Contact Form 7

I tried the plugin code and it worked perfect!