# WordPress adding <br> tags into plugin content

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, formatting, the-content

We've written a plugin that shows reviews upon usage of a shortcode.  On some sites, Wordpress is adding `<br>` tags throughout the shortcode content, and others it does not.

[The shortcode works here (Nearby Now)](http://servicepros.nearbynow.co/plugins/wordpress-plugins/recent-reviews-plugin-example/).

[The shortcode has tags inserted here (Dent Biz).](http://www.dentbiz.com/reviews/)

There's a couple of articles [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/automatically-added-brs-and-paragraphs) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11134/stray-p-elements) that recommend adding tho following code to the functions.php file.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

I've tried this on the 2nd site above (Dent Biz), but it doesn't fix the problem.  Also, I've tried disabling all other plugins on the site with no success.  I would hope there was an easy way to prevent WordPress from molesting the html returned by the plugin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Infocus theme was the culprit.  Deactivating it immediately solved the problem.

Their support forum recommended using the [raw][/raw] shortcode surrounding our shortcode, which allowed us to use our plugin with the Infocus theme.

[raw][recentreviews radius="15" count="3" zoomlevel="10"][/raw]